# How can I print out the result of evaluation of the expression. I can't seem to find a way to print Val

Tags: haskell, interpreter

I made the pattern where if you give it only a number it's gonna return the Value. I would just add deriving (Show) to Val as well but that doesn't work because of (Val->Val) (that's what I understood from the error messages). Anyone know what I could do ?

```hs
import GHC.Show (Show)
type Var = String 

-- Expressions of source code in the form of a Abstract syntax tree
data Exp = Enum Int         -- constant
        |Evar Var           -- variable
        |Elet Var Exp Exp   -- expr "let x = e1 in e2"
        |Ecall Exp Exp      -- Function call
        deriving (Show)

-- returned values
data Val = Vnum Int         -- Whole number
        |Vprim (Val->Val)   -- A primitive
        

mkPrim::(Int->Int->Int)->Val
mkPrim f = Vprim(\(Vnum x) -> Vprim (\(Vnum y) -> Vnum (f x y)))

-- Initial environement that contains all primitives
type Env = [(Var, Val)]
pervasive::Env
pervasive = [("+", mkPrim (+)), ("-", mkPrim (-)),("*", mkPrim (*)), ("/", mkPrim div)]

eval::Env->Exp->Val
eval pervasive (Enum n) = Vnum n

sampleExp = Elet "x" (Enum 3) (Ecall (Ecall (Evar "+") (Evar "x")) (Enum 4))

main = do print(eval pervasive (Enum 4))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If `eval` returns a `Vprim`, what do you want to see appear on your screen?

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing a custom `Show` instance:

```
instance Show Val where
  show (Vnum n) = show n
  show (Vprim _) = "<prim>"
```

This however shall make printed primitives indistinguishable. It might be convenient to equip prims with names:

```
data Val = Vnum Int | Vprim String (Val -> Val) 

instance Show Val where
  show (Vnum n) = show n
  show (Vprim name _) = name
```